# Streamlit app work local but not in deploying

Tags: python, heroku, streamlit

i’m new to streamlit and i’m trying to make a financial dashboard of the markets. In local the code i created work perfectly but now that I’ve deployed it on Heroku appears a strange error on a string that in local works! I don’t know why this happen… This is the error code that appears:

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/streamlit/script_runner.py", line 324, in _run_script
exec(code, module.**dict**)
File "/app/first_app.py", line 55, in 
df_eu = investpy.get_index_recent_data(index='MSCI Europe Net EUR',country='euro zone') # europa
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/investpy/indices.py", line 251, in get_index_recent_data
raise RuntimeError("ERR#0034: country " + country.lower() + " not found, check if it is correct.")

I think the error should be in the first line (line 324) but i don’t know how to solve it.

I’m using these libraries:
streamlit
pandas
numpy
investpy
urlopen
BeautifulSoup4

I was thinking that these should be a problem of the financial library “investpy”, but everywhere it works!

Heroku sets the region to default US, while i’m in Europe: can this be the problem?

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has nothing to with the Heroku server choice (or even steamlit) since `investpy` simply scrapes fundamental financial information  from the Investing.com.

[Reference](https://investpy.readthedocs.io/_api/indices.html?highlight=get_index#investpy.indices.get_index_recent_data)

Your issue lies with the call of the function `get_index_recent_data` when you pass the country parameter.

Just make a simple script to use that. Run some unittests or debug with some values manually to see where does the problem lie in the logic